# Laravel Application | Only Safari is sometimes missing XSRF Cookie on Requests

Tags: laravel, cookies, safari, csrf, inertiajs

We've recently deployed a Laravel Application and experienced some weird issues with Some Safari Versions on our application.

When surfing on our applications, especially if the user is not authorized, we sometimes have on Safari the Problem that the XSRF-Token is not present within the Request/Response-Header.

On application Forms, the missing token results in a 419 Page expired issue.

The Problem only appears sometimes in some versions of Safari. Mostly a Reset Cache & Cookies fixes the Problem for 1 or 2 form request.

I did a complete reset of Safari

- Allowed Cookie
- Allowed Tracking
- Disabled Plug-Ins

**Technology**

We use PHP 8.0 and the latest Laravel release. For the Frontend, there is a vue.js application with inertia.js as a connector. Regarding passing csrf-tokens to the Frontend, there is no further configuration needed to pass down the csrf-token. ([Soruce](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/issues/32))

[image]

I tried to capture the TokenMismatchExpection but no chance only the HTTPException works.

The question I have:

- Does anybody experience similar problems? How can I prevent them?

Attached some Laravel Debugbar Screenshots.

left side Safari 14.03 | right side Chrome

[image]

Page expired screen

[image]

Comment: Like it's mentioned in the source you provided: you don't need to handle anything CSRF-related since Axios resolves it all under the hood. I would recommend that either try to debug axios and set up some breakpoints, or create an issue on their github. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues

Comment: We also run a reasonably large website and have this issue with about 3% of our users (Which ends up being tens of thousands of 419 errors a week). Browser, OS and location don't seem to matter. We have not been able to work out what's going on. Sometimes the cookie is sent back to us on a request, but the token is incorrect and for other users its not set at all. We have not been able to reproduce this issue making it near possible to fix. Happy to try and work this out with you if you are still having this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in the same issue. I pinned the problem down to Safari ignoring the 'Set-Cookie' response header if the page was opened via a link from another site. (In my case, it's a link in an email opened in MailHog). If the link is opened in a new tab by hand, the problem is gone.

Due to the missing `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie, axios doesn't set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header in the requests leading to the `419` from Laravel.

So far I haven't found a feasible solution to inject the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header by hand because the the `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware expects the token to be an encrypted cookie.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Did you find a solution for this yet?